# How can I calculate SSIM between 2 images using scikit-image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I am trying to find the SSIM between two images that I'm storing using the Image data structure from PIL. the structural_similarity function requires both images to be stored as numpy arrays of the same shape, but despite me supplying such arrays, I keep getting an error suggesting they are not in fact the same shape.

The error I keep getting comes from the structural_similarity function, with the error being:

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)
```

My code looks as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity

def readAndResize(image_path, width=60, height=30):
    try:
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        image = image.resize((width, height))
        return image
    except:
        print("Error: Could not read the image at", image_path)
        return []
    
def computeMeasure1(image1, image2):
        img1 = np.asarray(image1)
        img2 = np.asarray(image2)
        print(img1.shape)  # prints (30, 60, 3)
        print(img2.shape)  # prints (30, 60, 3)
        measure_value = structural_similarity(img1, img2, win_size=(3,3), multichannel=True)
        return measure_value

def main():
    
    path = "Images/Student_Test/generated.photos_v3_0228313.jpg"
    path2 = "Images/Student_Train/6_img_1553496386570.jpg"

    image = (readAndResize(path))
    image2 = (readAndResize(path2))

    print(computeMeasure1(image,image2))

main()
```

I have tried to store the images using imread() from opencv-python, but the exact same problem persisted, with the same error popping up despite both arrays being the same shape.

Comment: What images are you trying to store?  Where in you code does the error occur? The message is saying that you have two 1D array, one of length 3 and the other of length 2. They are not 2D images. What are these?

Comment: The error occurs at the structural_similarity function call. They are just regular 2d images of ai-generated faces, and for reasons unknown to me it's just that specific function that seems to be having trouble - when I try to compute MSE instead of SSIM (also from skimage), everything works as it should, leading me to believe I'm just not using the function correctly, and the error isn't in the way I'm storing the images or in the nature of the images.

Comment: Print the shape of each image just before the call to SSIM to be sure your images are 2D and have the same shapes.

Comment: I have done that as seen in the code, right before the SSIM function gets called.

Comment: Why have you put parentheses around the right side? `image = (readAndResize(path))`

Comment: I'm not sure why I've done that, but afaik it doesn't make any difference in Python

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, `win_size=(3,3)` should be a single value, not a tuple

Comment: Exactly, and I'm just saying that's what it shouldn't look like

Comment: So what _should_ it look like?